# using linux command line to format and partition an sd card for raspberry pi

Tags: partition

I need help understanding how to format and partition and sd card for raspberry pi 4 from linux command line please. I have downloaded an iso image for raspian light (not noobs).

Question: If I am not using noobs do I still need a fat32 partition?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> do I still need a fat32 partition

Yes, that is required for booting.  The Raspbian card layout is much simpler than the NOOBs one though; there are two partitions, one little vfat one for the boot partition and a much bigger ext4 one which is the root filesystem.

Creating a card from the command-line is dead simple: **You do not have to format the card first or anything**, as it does not matter what is already on it. If there is anything on it though, and it is currently mounted, you should unmount that first.  But to be clear: It doesn't matter what has been done or not done to the card.  This process will overwrite everything and create a complete SD card with two partitions.

```
sudo dd if=raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress
```

The only trick here is which `/dev` node to use.  First, it obviously has to refer to the card and not your harddrive, etc.  Be sure about that.  The second issue, which confuses a lot of people, is that it should be for the card as a whole and not partitions on it.

```
/dev/sdb   <- Refers to the whole card/device.  USE THIS
/dev/sdb1  <- Refers to a partition on the device.
```

Similarly, `mmcblk0` and `mmcblk0p1`; use the first one.  In both cases you want the node **without** the numerical suffix (other that the 0 in mmcblk0).

If you get that correct, the process is pretty bulletproof.  See `man dd` for details about that tool.

Comment: the sd card does not have a partition table or files system currently - does the dd command take care of those items or do I need to create those please? I do have the GParted gui app installed on my computer

Comment: thank you - your solution worked and now I am able to boot - success!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I can no longer mount the sdcard (64GB) and Gparted shows warning signs on the two partitions (Fat32, and Ext4). No dostools, even though I have them installed. I would like to be able to mount the sdcard so that I can add WiFI and SSH configuration because I'm installing a headless image.