# Ejected SD-Card while Pi was running | Repair SD-Card?

Tags: sd-card

my Pi froze Up and i couldnt get it to start anymore - i turned it on and off but i just couldnt connect via ssh anymore (got connection refused)
i thought i broke the image and so i wanted to eject the sd card (while the pi was running) and reflash it
but i wasnt able to flash the card anymore

quick formating (windows) is working

sdcard formatter doesnt (Formatting failed)

is there any programm i can use to repair this sd-card or do i have to buy a new one

Comment: Try formatting it in a camera or cell-phone or tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried everything without success

i even copied some stuff to the card and restarted my pc just to see if the data is still t here but it wasnt so i think the card is just done

ty guys for your replies

Answer (score 1):

1. Download BalenaEtcher from https://www.balena.io/etcher/ Choose Windows and Install into System.
2. Download Zip from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/
3. Put ur Damaged Sd Card into Card reader and put into System, and Open Balena Etcher, In First step select ur zip, In Second Step do u see ur damaged Card ? If yes than go to Third step which must be success.

But If that does not help, try to clean ur sd card using some system partition utility

Comment: i already cleaned the card via cmd // i am seeing my card in etcher and the burning process starts but im getting "the writer process ended unexpectedly. please try again, and contact the etcher team if the problem persists." no matter what image i try

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any program I can use to repair this SD card?

Technically the card does not need to be formatted before you burn a Pi OS image to it, since that will overwrite any previous formatting anyway.  As I understand it, the reason you need to format it first on MS Windows is because some of the tools used there to burn the image won't do anything with the card until it is formatted.

However, if you use a low level tool such `dd`, available on linux and other POSIX systems (including I think macOS, and apparently on Windows via *MinGW*), it does not care about the current state of the card.

[Using `dd` to burn an OS image to an SD card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/102285/5538)

If there's something seriously wrong with the card this will probably fail with an error,<sup>1</sup> but there are no actual integrity checks, so you may want to compare the card to the original image afterward with a tool like `cmp` or `diff`.<sup>2</sup>  If not just pop it in the Pi and see.

---

1. If that happens the card is truly defunct and cannot be fixed.
2. There are perhaps more efficient ways to do this, point being the first N bytes read from the SD card's device node (whatever you used as `of` with `dd`) should be identical to the first N bytes from the image file (whatever you used as `if` with `dd`).

Comment: For binary comparison I would prefer `cmp`.

Comment: @Ingo Good idea.